sampling unbalanced data frame columns
If I have a data frame df, which has five columns: 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', and 'E', which contains python strings. Currently, 'B', 'C', 'D', and 'E' has unbalanced unique values (i.e., some unique values have more rows than the others). How can I sample df so that column 'B', 'C', 'D', and 'E' have balanced number of unique values (i.e., each unique value in a specific column has the same number of rows)? I want to sample with replacement so that the resulting data frame has the same length as the original data frame, though some rows may be duplicated and some may be omitted. Thanks!

please create a minimal reproducible example and your expected output

Also the expected behavior is unclear. Should the sampling be per column (=independant) or are the values linked in a row? Make sure to clearly explain what you want ant to provide meaningful examples to demonstrate this.
